# Cannot find Language-Definition for APK

Tags: android, apk

i am developing an app for android.
But when I upload the apk to my developer console, it is marked with 60 languages. (1 default + 59 others).

But I only made it in German.
Where can I define the languages... I searched so hard but did not find anything :(

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the appcompat v7 library which comes with about that many translations and the toolchain currently includes the library by default when creating new projects. There can be other libraries that contribute to the number of languages, too.